# Cannot write files from Lua in Scite on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, lua, scite

Using Scite 4.1.3 on Windows 10.

I tried the following Lua script:

```lua
function TestFile()
  mycontent = "Hello World"

  mytmpfilename = os.tmpname()

  os.execute("echo aaaa > " .. mytmpfilename) -- create file explicitly;

  mytmpfile = io.popen(mytmpfilename, "w") -- w+ crashes Scite in Windows!
  mytmpfile:write(mycontent)
  mytmpfile:close()
  print("readall " .. mytmpfilename .. ": " .. io.popen(mytmpfilename, "r"):read("*a"))
end
```

If I run this, I get printed:

```
readall C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Temp\s8qk.m:
```

... which means Lua could not even read this file?! And also, this stupid Windows Explorer prompt shows up:

[image: windows explorer]

At end, the content of the `C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Temp\s8qk.m` is still just `aaaa`.

So obviously, `mytmpfile:write` part fails silently, and nothing new is written in the file - the only thing that wrote to the file is the `echo aaaa > ...` executed by `cmd.exe` via `os.execute`.

So my question is - how can I write a file with Lua in Scite on Windows? Preferably, without having that stupid "How do you want to open this file?" prompt show up?

Answer (score 3):

Eh, I think I got it ...

See, the OP example uses `io.popen` - and, if we look at https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html it says:

> popen, pclose - pipe stream to or from a **process**

(emphasis mine).

So, basically, if under Windows I try to do `io.popen(filename)`, then apparently tries to find the *process* that would be the default "opener" for that file type ... and also therefore the prompt I'm being shown in the OP (and therefore, I could never read or write the files accessed -- or rather, *not* accessed -- in that way).

However, [Programming in Lua : 21.2 – The Complete I/O Model](https://www.lua.org/pil/21.2.html) actually uses `io.open` (notice, no `p` for process); and then the files seem to open for read/write fine.

So, corrected example from OP should be:

```lua
function TestFile()
  mycontent = "Hello World"

  mytmpfilename = os.tmpname()

  -- os.execute("echo aaaa > " .. mytmpfilename) -- create file explicitly; -- no need anymore, with io.open

  mytmpfile = io.open(mytmpfilename, "w+") -- w+ crashes Scite in Windows, but only if using io.popen; is fine with io.open!
  mytmpfile:write(mycontent)
  mytmpfile:close()
  print("readall " .. mytmpfilename .. ": " .. io.open(mytmpfilename, "r"):read("*a"))
end
```